# How to generate Invoice on submitting a form

Tags: php

**Here is the  HTML Code I have used**

```
 <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Registration</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <style>
        #container{
        width:350px;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        color:#82ABEA;
        }
        label{
        display:block;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        }
        fieldset{
        border-color:#82ABEA;
        }
        button{
        background-color:#900;
        color:#FFF;
        border:none;
        box-shadow:none;
        width:80px;
        height:30px;
        }
        a{
        color:#82ABEA;
        }
        </style>
        </head>

        <body>
    <div id="container">
    <p><b><a href="view_rec.php">View Record</a></b></p>
    <form method="post" action="save_reg.php">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><b>Register Here</b></legend>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input placeholder="Type Your First Name Here" type="text" name="firstname" size="25"/><br/><br/>

    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input placeholder="Type Your Last Name Here" type="text" name="lastname" size="25"/><br/><br/>

    <label>Mobile Number</label>
    <input placeholder="Type Your Mobile Number Here" type="text" name="mobilenumber" size="25"/><br/><br/>

    <label>Email Id</label>
    <input placeholder="Type Your Email ID Here" type="text" name="emailid" size="25"/><br/><br/>

    <label>Gender</label>
    <input placeholder="Select A Gender" type="radio"  name="gender" value="Male"/>Male
    <input placeholder="Type Your Mobile Number Here" type="radio"  name="gender"  value="Female"/>Female<br/><br/>

    <label>Date Of Birth</label>
    <select name="db">
    <option selected>Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>

    </select>
    <select name="dbd">
    <option selected>Day</option>
    <option>01</option>
    <option>02</option>
    <option>03</option>
    <option>04</option>
    <option>05</option>
    <option>06</option>
    <option>07</option>
    <option>08</option>
    <option>09</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    </select>

    <select name="dby">
    <option selected>Year</option>
    <option>2005</option>
    <option>2006</option>
    <option>2007</option>
    <option>2008</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2013</option>
    <option>2014</option>
    <option>2015</option>
    <option>2016</option>
    </select><br/><br/>

    <button><b>Submit</b></button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**on clicking submit button i need a invoice to be generated by using form values **
    **Can some help me out**

Comment: I need. And what you have to try for that so far?

Comment: You can find the PHP documentation [here](http://php.net/docs.php).

Comment: i have used this method......if(!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
echo"Data is not saved";
}else{
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo"<tr><th>First Name</th>";
echo"<th>Last Name</th>";
echo"</tr><tr>";
echo"<td>{$_POST['firstname']}</td>";
echo"<td>{$_POST['lastname']}</td>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"</table>";
}
?>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to set the save_reg.php file to something like this:

```
<html>
<body>

Your firstname <?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?><br>
Your lastname is: <?php echo $_POST["lastname"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

$_POST["name"] retrieves the value of the DOM object with the defined name in the form.

you can also set a variable for more readble code :

```
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.